# PayPal user to PayPal user checkout

Tags: paypal-rest-sdk

*can anyone tell me how to accomplish this?  Maybe point me in the right direction of a FAQ or tutorial?*
I can't find this in PayPal's API documentation.
 Using RESTful API...

Thanks

Comment: What is your question specifically?

Answer (score 0):

I want to create a `PayPal` to `PayPal transaction`, where I can specify both the buyer and the seller. All the documentation I've seen seems to only allow specification of the buyer.